# Struct values not being output to screen

Tags: c++, struct

I am working on a program and part of it requires me to create a struct called DETAILS with the fields name, age, and height. I want to populate the record with data using a function argument. I had numerous problems with this code and had lots of help from here but need a little more. I can't output the populated struct to the screen. If anyone could help me with this last thing I would be so grateful!

Here is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int LEN=100;

struct DETAILS
{
 char name[LEN];
 int age;
 double height;
};

 DETAILS fillperson(struct DETAILS David, const char[LEN], int, double);


int main()
{
 struct DETAILS David;

 fillperson(struct DETAILS David, "David Greene", 38, 180.0);

 cout<<David.name<<endl;
 cout<<David.age<<endl;
 cout<<David.height<<endl;

 return 0;
}

DETAILS fillperson(struct DETAILS David, char name[LEN], int age, double height) 
{
 cout<<"Done"<<endl;
 return;
}
```

Comment: I put them in as comments beside the lines they are referencing

Comment: You are mixing struct DETAILS and struct person. There is no struct person definition in your code, but you create a struct person instance called David. Change that first line in main from struct person David; to struct DETAILS David; and it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DETAILS fillperson(David, "David Greene", 38, 180.0); //deprecated conversion from string constant to char * [-Wwrite-Strings]
```

This is because string literals (like "David Greene") are `const`, and you're passing it as just a `char[LEN]`. Try `const char[LEN]`.

```
DETAILS fillperson(struct DETAILS, char[LEN] name, int age, double height) //expected , or ... before 'name'
```

The `[]` goes after the name of the variable: `char name[LEN]`.

Also, where is this `David` variable coming from? The name of the variable needs to be in the function signature (`struct DETAILS David`, not just `struct DETAILS`).

```
cin>>David.name>>name;
```

I think what you really want is:

```
DETAILS fillperson(struct DETAILS David, const char name[LEN], int age, double height)
```

### EDIT:

I think you misunderstood what I was saying. This line is a weird mix of function definition of function call.

```
DETAILS fillperson(struct DETAILS David, "David Greene", 38, 180.0);
```

When you call a function, you don't declare types:

```
fillperson(David, "David Greene", 38, 180.0);
```

But you do need them in the actual function definition, so instead of this:

```
DETAILS fillperson(struct DETAILS, char[LEN] name, int age, double height)
```

Do this:

```
DETAILS fillperson(struct DETAILS David, char name[LEN], int age, double height)
```

### EDIT 2:

Also, I don't know what you're trying to do here (or any of the similar lines):

```
cin>>David.name>>name;
```

Are you trying to copy the string? (See [strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/)) or read input (`cin >> David.name`)?

## Recommendation

If you're using C++ and C++ input streams, you should really just use `string`.

### EDIT 3

Your current code won't work for several reasons:

```
DETAILS fillperson(struct DETAILS David, char name[LEN], int age, double height) 
{
    cout<<"Done"<<endl;
    return;
}
```

The function signature says the function returns `DETAILS` (the first part of the line), but you don't return anything. Either return the input struct:

```
return David;
```

Or make the method return `void` (nothing):

```
void fillperson(...
```

My recommendation about using `string` is that it's much easier to work with than straight character arrays (`char[]`):

string name = "David";
string name2 = name; // Copying is much easier

So for example, your code could look like this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct DETAILS
{
    string name;
    int age;
    double height;
};

// Note that I'm passing a reference for DETAILS (the &). This means
// that we have access to the actual DETAILS instance from outside
// the method, not just a copy.
void fillperson(struct DETAILS&, const string, int, double);

int main()
{
    struct DETAILS David;

    fillperson(David, "David Greene", 38, 180.0);

    cout<<David.name<<endl;
    cout<<David.age<<endl;
    cout<<David.height<<endl;

    return 0;
}

void fillperson(struct DETAILS &person, const string name, int age, double height) 
{
    person.name = name;
    person.age = age;
    person.height = height;
    cout<<"Done"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Sorry the person tag should not have been in my code. I amended it here and I implemented the changes you suggested however I am getting a lot of strange compiler errors now such as this: /usr/include/c++/4.6/iomanip:229:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Setw)

Comment: Thanks so much Brendan. I have been at it so long I completely muddled up the code and ruined it then couldn't see the obvious errors. I just deleted the cin statements and it worked. Thanks so much for the help really appreciate it.

Comment: What do you mean by just use string? Instead of what? Also, if you wouldn't mind taking another quick look at my question, I've come up against another error!

Comment: @adohertyd - Edited it again.

Comment: @BrendanLong - are you missing the include for `string`?

Comment: @prelic - `string` is available in `iostream`.

Answer (score 1):

```
person fillperson(struct DETAILS, char[LEN] name, int age, double height)
```

should be:

```
struct person fillperson(struct DETAILS,char name[LEN], int age, double height)
```

I can't give you a more complete answer without the definition of `struct person`

edit:

This line doesn't make any sense:

```
DETAILS fillperson(struct DETAILS David, "David Greene", 38, 180.0);
```

Perhaps it should be:

```
fillperson(struct DETAILS David, "David Greene", 38, 180.0);
```

As stated above, you shouldn't be using C-style strings with C++ streams.  Pick a language and use those constructs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated my code and my question. Would you mind please taking another look? Would really appreciate it thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the input. Have another edit to the question if you wouldn't mind. I'm new to structs and this should be basic but I just can't get it to work. Also. what do you mean by using strings vs streams?

Comment: @adohertyd - If you add `#include <string>`, it works perfectly.  Tested in VS